# SpringBoot OAuth 2 with Mulple Login URL

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0

I'm following this [article](https://www.devglan.com/spring-security/spring-boot-security-oauth2-example) and my application is also the same pattern. But I need multiple Login URL like

- /loginUrl1
- /loginUrl2
- /loginUrl3

instead of single currently URL is /oauth/token

Here's also my similar **AuthorizationServer**

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
 public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

static final String CLIEN_ID = "devglan-client";
static final String CLIENT_SECRET = "devglan-secret";
static final String GRANT_TYPE = "password";
static final String AUTHORIZATION_CODE = "authorization_code";
static final String REFRESH_TOKEN = "refresh_token";
static final String IMPLICIT = "implicit";
static final String SCOPE_READ = "read";
static final String SCOPE_WRITE = "write";
static final String TRUST = "trust";
static final int ACCESS_TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS = 1*60*60;
static final int FREFRESH_TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS = 6*60*60;

@Autowired
private TokenStore tokenStore;

@Autowired
private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

@Override
public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer configurer) throws Exception {

    configurer
            .inMemory()
            .withClient(CLIEN_ID)
            .secret(CLIENT_SECRET)
            .authorizedGrantTypes(GRANT_TYPE_PASSWORD, AUTHORIZATION_CODE, REFRESH_TOKEN, IMPLICIT )
            .scopes(SCOPE_READ, SCOPE_WRITE, TRUST)
            .accessTokenValiditySeconds(ACCESS_TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS).
            refreshTokenValiditySeconds(FREFRESH_TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS);
}

@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
    endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore)
            .authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
}
```

}

**ResourceServerConfig**

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

private static final String RESOURCE_ID = "resource_id";

@Override
public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) {
    resources.resourceId(RESOURCE_ID).stateless(false);
}

@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.
            anonymous().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/users/**").authenticated()
            .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(new OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler());
}
```

}

Here's my **SecurityConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
 public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Resource(name = "userService")
private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Override
@Bean
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
}

@Autowired
public void globalUserDetails(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
            .passwordEncoder(encoder());
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .csrf().disable()
            .anonymous().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api-docs/**").permitAll();
}

@Bean
public TokenStore tokenStore() {
    return new InMemoryTokenStore();
}

@Bean
public BCryptPasswordEncoder encoder(){
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}

@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean corsFilter() {
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
    config.setAllowCredentials(true);
    config.addAllowedOrigin("*");
    config.addAllowedHeader("*");
    config.addAllowedMethod("*");
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
    FilterRegistrationBean bean = new FilterRegistrationBean(new CorsFilter(source));
    bean.setOrder(0);
    return bean;
}
```

}

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand the question.  It sounds like you want to be able to login against multiple auth servers?  If this is the case, I would highly recommend upgrading to Spring Boot 2, which has Spring Security 5, which in turn contains in built support for OAuth2 (rather than using the external spring-security-oauth project).  What is good in Spring Security 5 is that is has very good support for defining multiple OAuth2 Authentication servers which your application can use.

Comment: I would recommend reading the doco: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.9.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#jc-oauth2login  I found the sample code very helpful as well.

Comment: Currently my login URL is localhost:8080/oauth/token but I need three custom Login URL. That's what I need. 
BTW I'm already using SpringBoot 2

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why you need three custom login url's.  What are you trying to achieve?  If you're using Spring Boot 2, then I would strongly suggest that you use Spring Security 5's inbuilt support for OAuth2 clients instead of the separate project,

Comment: I want to apply Role Base Login therefore want to do...
Do you have any other solution ?

Comment: Because I have three different Frontend application and all accessing same server